# How do I delete kernels from a server?

Tags: kernel

I need to delete older kernels from a server to make room for updating to a new one. I can't really use GUI-based methods like `synaptic`, and `apt-get remove --purge` didn't work.

What to do?

Comment: What do you mean by “apt-get remove --purge didn't work”? What command did you run, what happened? Be sure to copy-paste the command and any error message.

Comment: Can i know if your GUI is not at all working??(meaning you cant use my solution of an alternate gui tool) or is it that you are not able to use GUI tools like synaptic??

Answer (score 7):

Create a shell script with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
dpkg -l linux-*  | \
awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | \
grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | \
grep  -e '[0-9]' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

This script will remove old kernels, headers and sources.

Comment: You, Sir, are the king ! :) ...Freed up 70% of my diskspace on server thx to this

Comment: works :) im on ubuntu server, cant install gui tool

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to run

```
apt-get --purge autoremove
```

? That does the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

This Article details for remove old kernel linux 
http://www.ibotme.com/knowledgebase/linux-existe-alguna-manera-de-ocultar-o-eliminar-las-versiones-anteriores-de-kernel/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

Download and install either of these from software center:

- Janitor
- Ubuntu Tweak(it has the janitor built in it)

Open Janitor(direct janitor or tweak), you will find "Old Kernel Packages" under "System". Tick mark on it and click 'Clean'

Enter the password and the old ones will be removed