# Is it safe to remove extra GRUB2 entries from updated Kernel versions?

Tags: 12.04, grub2

After installing an OS/kernel update through Ubuntu's built-in Update Manager (or Software Updater), a new boot menu entry is added (one with the latest kernel) and the previous boot menu entry is kept in GRUB.

I'm just wondering if these two boot menu entry are pointing at the same OS. I want to keep storage redundancy as minimal as possible. To add to this, running "update-grub" shows that the two entries point to the same partition.

That said, how do I safely remove the older boot menu entry? I know I can do it through GRUB Customizer, but I want to make sure it won't break anything and that it's not just an illusion.

Answer (score 3):

If the new version of the kernel is working and you dont notice any glitches compared with while you were using the previous one you are more than welcome to remove previous installed kernel images.

There are a few posts on the site that might help you with it, you can also use the suggested GRUB customizer:

- [Removing old kernel entries in Grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176322/removing-old-kernel-entries-in-grub)
- [How to delete kernel entries in the Grub 2 menu whose kernels are removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149814/how-to-delete-kernel-entries-in-the-grub-2-menu-whose-kernels-are-removed)

Have a look at those for help. Normally I always leave the latest and the latest -1 versions installed, just in case.